# not all ":)" in the string is replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my snippet where I have lots of ":)" but only one ":)" is replace, any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var mm = "Hello :) hai there :) :)";
  
  $("#mm").text(mm.replace(":)","[emo_smile]"));
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mm"></div>
```

Comment: How about using while loop?
`while(mm.indexOf(":)") != -1) mm = mm.relpace(":)", "[emo_smile]");`

Comment: Use RegExp: `.replace(/:\)/g,"[emo_smile]")`

Comment: @Mephiztopheles I got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /:)/: Unmatched ')'" after trying your suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: It's because you're using the wrong regular expression. Try the one Mephiztopheles suggested. You must escape the closing parentheses as it is a special character in regular expressions.

Comment: yap :) the ")" character is a key used in regex to define (close) a capturing group so you have to escape it using backslash